# Using Git to select a subset of files

Tags: git, github, markdown, gitbook, google-slides

### Introduction

So I'm building a course that is comprised of a textbook (a set of Markdown files), some sample code (for homeworks and projects) and slides (right now in Google Slides).

The Textbook is published using a Markdown publishing tool called GitBook, which allows me to use GitHub to host all of the markdown files and automatically compiles them into a nice styled web UI for reading. It also allows for translated versions of the book to be included in a specific way so that it can be read in multiple languages.

Currently the book is hosted in two separate Github repositories, one for the concepts (or lectures) and one for the practicals (lab exercises).

The code is also stored in two Github repositories: solution code and starter apps.

The slides are currently all up on Google Slides.

### Problem

I'm looking to organize (or reorganize) this course with the following in mind:

1. The course needs to be modular. It will be taught in many different  environments, with some being very thorough, and some being quite short. This means that I would like to somehow tag different parts of the course so that I could pull together different versions of the course (perhaps a three day version would include only the fundamentals, but a week long seminar could include extra modules). Ideally, I could use the same markers for the textbook, the code and the slides, so I could automatically pull together the correct "package".
2. The GitBook requires a specific file structure in the repository, so I can't change too much around there.
3. The slides are currently not even in a repository, since they are in a Google Slide format, but it would be pretty amazing to move them over as wells o everything could be in one place (maybe some sort of Markdown as well? Would have to convert it though).

### What I Have Tried

I'm not really sure where to start with organizing all this content, I was thinking about moving everything into one repository, and using submodules to keep things organized, but I don't have much experience with this.

Also thought about using different branches for the different versions, but it seems like that would add a ton of work because I have to independently update each branch when there is a change if there are files in common.

Tags also came to mind, but as those are for commits and not files, not sure how that would help.

Any suggestions? Tools? Ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Nikita

Comment: This question is extremely broad, and is also asking for opinions rather than solutions. Please break it down into smaller individual questions.

Comment: I agree this is a very broad question. May I suggest [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt). That should at least give you some ideas to narrow your question down.

Comment: You might want to consider migrating your slides to this: https://github.com/gnab/remark

Comment: In terms of the rest of the questions, this isn't really something that someone can answer definitively.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I understand the question is broad, but since it's an overall organization question I'm not sure how to narrow it down further. My question was definitely more opinion based then solution based, as I understand there are many ways to do this. I'll definitely check out subtrees and remark, thanks for the tip!

Comment: My main question was the one regarding multiple release version of the same book. The course will have a 3 day, one week, and 5 week long version, with each one building upon the shorter one. Since there are files in common for all of these, I would like some way to "tag" or mark the files as necessary for each version, and then I could do some sort of "git checkout -- threeday" or something like that that would have only the docs required for that specific version. I could use branches but then any changes would have to be remade in each one. Thoughts?

Comment: @NikitaGamolsky my approach would be to use something like git-subtree  to easily copy updates/changes from the master branch to the various other branches. The trick would be to organize your directory structure so that git-subtree can easily be told which files go where. However, without a lot for info from you, it would be difficult to provide any specific direction. I outlined a slightly different use-case for git-subtree [here](https://gist.github.com/waylan/4505033). Perhaps that will give you some ideas. I would suggest trying something and coming back with more specific questions.